# I need help to save the file at the directory path

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I have the code to save a file in a folder in directory

```
string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy.HH-mm-ss");
var file = File.Create("Owe-Data.txt" + timestamp);

var com = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase + timestamp + @"\Data" + file;

MessageBox.Show(com);
if (!Directory.Exists(com))
{
      Directory.CreateDirectory(com);
}
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(com))
{
      sw.WriteLine(InputData);
}
```

I Displayed COM it gives path but I can't see the Data folder or Owe-Data file at that path.
Can anybody can tell why this happening? or should I save the Data folder in the current directory where this program is running?

The problem is I don't know how to reach that path?

Working on windows phone 5, visual studio 2008 .NET framwork 2.0

Comment: What is the value of `com` exactly?

Comment: are you getting any error

Comment: i just save the directory path in com variable 
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase + timestamp + @"\Data" + file;

Comment: @Microsoft DN : No its not giving any error bt it should save the file in C:\Programe files but the file is not there

Comment: @Microsoft DN : the path displayed by MessageBox.Show(com); is \Programe Files\OWEScanner\OWEScanner.exe11-21-2013.15-56-17\Owe-DataSystem.IO.FileStream
but when i check at this path file and folder(Data) is not there

Comment: @Microsoft DN : I tried  using (var sw = new StreamWriter(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase + @"\\Data" + timestamp + File.Create("Owe-Data.txt" + timestamp)))

                    {

                        sw.WriteLine(InputData);

                    } now its giving IO exception

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're trying to create a directory with the value of the variable `com`, and then write to it as if it is a file. That won't work, obviously.

Comment: :yes i m saving directory path in com variable and then write to it, plz suggest any solution ?

Comment: I tried  using (var sw = new StreamWriter(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase + @"\\Data" + timestamp + File.Create("Owe-Data.txt" + timestamp)))

                    {

                        sw.WriteLine(InputData);

                    } now its giving IO exception

Comment: Add \Data to `com`, but only add the filename after you create the folder

Comment: var file = File.Create("OweData.txt" + timestamp);

                    var com = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase + @"\Data" + timestamp;

                    MessageBox.Show(com);
                    if (!Directory.Exists(com))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(com);
                        
                    }
                    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(com + "OweData.txt"))
                    {

                        sw.Write("Awais");

                    }
it still giving IO exception